# WPF set ComboBox to -1 index after click event of ComboBoxItem issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox which contains my categories. In this combobox I have also an item named <--NEW CATEGORY--> which has a click event. For now, lets forget about that it opens a new window or dialog window to add a new category ... now I want  whenever the <--NEW CATEGORY--> is selected the combo box selected index change to -1.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="testcombo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="268,213,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Background="#FFC58383" DisplayMemberPath="data" SelectedValuePath="id">

                <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="ComboBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"/>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

and c#

```
namespace WpfApp4
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class Modell
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string data { get; set; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            testcombo.Items.Add(new Modell { id = 0, data = "<--NEW-->" });
            testcombo.Items.Add(new Modell { id = 1 , data = "dddd" });
            testcombo.Items.Add(new Modell { id = 2, data = "dddzxcd" });
            testcombo.Items.Add(new Modell { id = 3, data = "ddczdd" });
        }



        private void ComboBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var cat_obj = (sender as ComboBoxItem).Content as Modell;

            if (cat_obj.id == 0)
            {
                testcombo.SelectedIndex = -1;
                //MessageBox.Show("", "", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the above code does not change index to -1 but when I add a message box after or before the line `testcombo.SelectedIndex = -1;`it works :|

**note:** I cannot do the index to -1 in combobox SelectionChanged since in main project I have keyUp event that chooses the item by keyboard arrowUp/Down

Comment: Remove "New Category" item from combobox and create a button "New Category", which after new category created will add this category to the combobox items.

Comment: Another approach to set index in the code where you open a window for "New Cateogry".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Dispatcher` to make it works:

```
private void ComboBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var cat_obj = (sender as ComboBoxItem).Content as Modell;

    if (cat_obj.id == 0)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { testCombo.SelectedIndex = -1; }));
        //MessageBox.Show("", "", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }

}
```

Another solution could be:

```
private void ComboBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var cat_obj = (sender as ComboBoxItem).Content as Modell;

    if (cat_obj.id == 0)
    {
        testCombo.SelectedIndex = -1;
        e.Handled = true;
        testCombo.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }
}
```

The problem was, that combobx do item selection after `MouseLeftButtonUp` occurs and so override `SelectedIndex = -1;`. With Dispatcher you override the SelectedIndex, wich was set with mouse click. With second solution `e.Handled = true;` combobox doesn't select the item at all, but then you need to close the dropdown manually.

Comment: thank you @Rekshino ... is that means the event does not have enough time to do that (seems like this)or what ?... because it confused me

Comment: @RouzbehZarandi You are welcome! :) I have updated my answer.